# Can an American General licensee operate in Portugal during a visit?

Tags: license, europe, portable, international-operating

I am an American and I have an American General License (k8axf), and I tried to make sense of all the legal documents to see if I can operate while visiting Portugal and I think I can under a CEPT CAT 2 Novice operator.
Can anyone verify if my conclusion is correct?

Comment: Yes, but the real question is, can you figure out what privileges a Category 2 certificate *gets you* in Portugal? After reading several dozen documents (mostly petitions for changes), I gather that it's not all of HF, and that there are power limits, but I can't find a single list anywhere.

Comment: Did you check with the ARRL?  My research on this implies they are the organization that would issue any temporary operating permits under these reciprocity agreements.  I'll give this link for others with the same question as a place to start: http://www.arrl.org/files/file/VEs/International%20Operating%20March%202022.pdf

Comment: I figured the privileges part here - https://www.anacom.pt/streaming/SAASsetembro2013Mod06062016EN.pdf?contentId=1388097&field=ATTACHED_FILE. This came straight from ANACOM which is the Portuguese FCC. 
I was just trying to validate my research. And it seems that @hobbs validates my conclusions. Please submit your Answer below.

Comment: Portugal is one of the few places that allows HF for CEPT novices.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can under the terms of the CEPT Novice Licence {ECC (05)06} of which Portugal and the United States are signatory to. The privileges are of a class 2 licence, and frequencies and power limits are detailed [Here](https://www.anacom.pt/streaming/SAASsetembro2013Mod06062016EN.pdf?contentId=1388097&field=ATTACHED_FILE). It includes many HF privileges (mostly in the phone bands) and some VHF priveleges.
The ARRL publishes resources about international operation that you may want to look into.

Answer (score 0):

You can operate temporary as a visitor if you have the US Extra class license. In another case you need have the CEPT certificate and permanent residency. Anacom does not accept US credentials. Anatoly CT7BCL/AD8EQ